# How to full root a stock-root only Android device?

Tags: rooting, root-access

I have an Android device, that is a Chinese TV device that runs on Android 4.4.4. I'm developing an app that needs root access to properly function which I will then install on the device.

I can connect to the devices via ADB over WiFi and gain root access too.

[image: su via ADB is possible]

But I cannot gain root access from the app. A quick check by RootChecker app revealed that the "root access is not properly installed on the device". When my app tries to gain root access the error "uid xxx not allowed to su" occurs.

[Turns out that the device is only stock root/systemless root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611375/getting-error-uid-1000-not-allowed-to-su-on-runtime-exec-su)

So far, I've copied the su binary from my rooted Xiaomi Redmi 2 into the TV and replaced the /system/xbin/su with that file and changed the permissions. For some reason this did not work.

CPU model name of TV = ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)

CPU model name of phone = ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)

Since stock root is available, there must be a very straightforward way for me to root the device. Is it maybe possible to install TWRP on a device like this so that I can flash the SuperSU?

Answer (score 0):

You can push super su APK to /system/app and run the boot patching script manually but please make sure bootloader isn't locked and make a backup.

Comment: Can you please tell me which one is the "boot patching script"?
`99-supersu.sh` `99SuperSUDaemon` `install-recovery.sh` `otasurvival.sh `update-binary`